Flutter table calendar page transitions are not smooth, what should I do?
I created a table calendar and when I try to swipe left or right, the screen freezes for a moment before moving again. I don't know how to make it smoother. Please help me.
return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      child: TableCalendar(
                        sixWeekMonthsEnforced: true,
                        locale: 'vi',
                        headerVisible: false,
                        firstDay: DateTime.utc(1940, 12, 12),
                        lastDay: DateTime.utc(2040, 12, 12),
                        focusedDay: today,
                        onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
                          selectedMonthNotifier.value = focusedDay;
                          print('hi');
                        },
                        eventLoader: (day) {
                          return [_holidays[day], _lunarHolidays[day]] ?? [];
                        },
                        onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
                        startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
                        shouldFillViewport: true,
                        weekNumbersVisible: true,
                        daysOfWeekStyle: DaysOfWeekStyle(),
                        calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
                          markerBuilder: (context, date, events) {
                            bool isToday = isSameDay(date, DateTime.now());
                            final lunarDay = getLunarDay(date);
                            List<String> holidayEvents = [];
                            if (_holidays[date] != null) {
                              for (var event in _holidays[date]!) {
                                if (event is String) {
                                  holidayEvents.add(event);
                                }
                              }
                            }

                            List<String> lunarEvents = [];
                            Lunar lunarDate = LunarSolarConverter.solarToLunar(
                              Solar(
                                solarYear: date.year,
                                solarMonth: date.month,
                                solarDay: date.day,
                              ),
                            );
                            DateTime lunarDateTime = DateTime.utc(
                              lunarDate.lunarYear ?? 0,
                              lunarDate.lunarMonth ?? 1,
                              lunarDate.lunarDay ?? 1,
                            );
                            if (_lunarHolidays[lunarDateTime] != null) {
                              for (var event
                                  in _lunarHolidays[lunarDateTime]!) {
                                if (event is String) {
                                  lunarEvents.add(event);
                                }
                              }
                            }
                            // print(lunarDateTime.day);
                            int index = -1;
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6, right: 6),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: isToday
                                          ? const Color.fromARGB(
                                              255, 188, 13, 0)
                                          : null,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                                  child: Text(
                                    isToday
                                        ? DateFormat.d().format(date)
                                        : '', // Hiển thị ngày dương
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  lunarDay, // Hiển thị ngày âm
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 0, left: 2, right: 2),
                                  height: 45,
                                  child: ListView(
                                    children: [
                                      (lunarDateTime.day == 14 ||
                                              lunarDateTime.day == 15)
                                          ? Column(
                                              children: [
                                                Icon(
                                                  Icons
                                                      .brightness_1, // Icon trăng tròn
                                                  color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                      255, 249, 249, 0),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            )
                                          : SizedBox(),
                                      ...holidayEvents.map((event) {
                                        index++;
                                        return Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              vertical: 2.0),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: solarHolidaysColors[index],
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                                          ),
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1),
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                '$event',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 10),
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }),
                                      ...lunarEvents.map((event) {
                                        index++;
                                        return Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              vertical: 2.0),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: lunarHolidaysColors[index],
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                                          ),
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1),
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                '$event',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 10),
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                          cellAlignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          markersAlignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          rowDecoration: BoxDecoration(),
                          cellMargin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(
                                255, 255, 255, 255), // Màu nền khi chọn
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 71, 71),
                                width: 2), // Viền hình chữ nhật
                            borderRadius: null, // Độ cong của góc
                          ),
                          selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          outsideDaysVisible: true,
                          outsideDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                  width: 0.5,
                                  color: const Color.fromARGB(
                                      255, 225, 225, 225))),
                          outsideTextStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                          ),
                          defaultDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                              border: Border.all(
                                  width: 0.5,
                                  color: const Color.fromARGB(
                                      255, 225, 225, 225))),
                          weekendDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                  width: 0.5,
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 225, 225))),
                          todayDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 71, 71),
                                width: 2),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          todayTextStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        daysOfWeekHeight: 25,
                        selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(day, today),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }

I thought the problem was:
    onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
                           selectedMonthNotifier.value = focusedDay;
                         },


But even if it's not drawn, when I hide it, the page transitions aren't smooth.
Do I need to display 3 calendar pages at a time? If so, what should I do?

This usually happens if you are calling setState({}) when changing the calendar page. Your valueNotifier might be triggering a setState somewhere in your code, please check that.
if you have to call setState when the page changes, maybe you should do it in a differed way after the transition is completed, something like the following could probably work:
onPageChanged: (DateTime focusedDay) async {
     Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
         selectedMonthNotifier.value = focusedDay;
     });
},


Thank you very much for your information, I realized the problem is that when I switch pages my calendar builder is called again as soon as I just scroll (the onPageChange event is not called yet). Is there a way for me to call the calendar builder after switching pages?

@HồNhậtTân I think this will not be possible, because as soon as you start scrolling, the calendar has to show already the calendar Items(days, header..etc) and thus has to call the calendar builder methods. I think you should not be doing any heavy data processing there. If you have to load data/do processing, consider doing it asynchronously when the onPageChanged is called, then call setState to refresh you calendar
